# Python Selenium scrape data string how to organize it? How to populate it as a Java like map?

Tags: python, string, selenium, format

So I'd like to scrape data from a website and compare this data with other websites data. In order to compare for instance prices, I guess I must put the scraped huge string to a java like map, in python a dictionary, but how to organize the string?
I didn't find an example about complex data organizing in python, just CSV imported pre-organised data formatting. CSV is not important yet, firstly I want to organize the data in a dictionary.

In Java, I populated an ArrayList with the scraped data, after regex the irrelevant ones and with the "organized" data I created a map.

```
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = ('https://uk.webuy.com/search/?stext=iphone%205c')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
delay = 3 # seconds

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
    print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__nuxt"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]').text

dataCEX = {element}

print(element)

print(dataCEX)

# with open('dataCEX.csv', mode='w') as csvFile:
#     for line in element:
#         csvFile.write(line)
driver.quit()
```